# Restrict local network to select IPs or MACs

Tags: wireless-networking, restrictions

I have a LAN to LAN connection between a primary router that has internet access and a secondary router used to extend the primary's wifi range
The secondary router has DHCP disabled

I was trying to restrict access to the local network to guests, so I had guest wifi turned on both routers. However, I realised after reading up online that guest wifi on the secondary wont work with such a setup

I came across this solution to try and get a WAN to LAN setup
[Guest wifi mode on a secondary router](https://superuser.com/questions/592121/guest-wifi-mode-on-a-secondary-router)

But, the problem with this solution is that my own devices wont see the local network when they are connected to the secondary router.

Is there any way I can set certain MACs to get complete access to the network and internet and restrict other devices on the DHCP to only get access to the internet

Comment: Can you provide the make and model of the devices invloved?

Answer (score 0):

"Guest WiFi" mode on consumer-grade routers is a convenient abstraction on a more complicated underlying network-architecture system. It simply doesn't give you the power you want.

The solution the page you linked has was to have a more complicated router which specifically "tags" certain packets from certain computers as being on different VLANS so that it can transmit them on the same wire as your "LAN" but the switch on the other side knows to treat them differently. I have a setup like this at my house, but it requires a bit of tinkering to get it to work correctly. I do *not* have "Guest WiFi" turned on though - and I don't have an access point which supports configuring Guest WiFi to use a separate VLAN. What I do instead (which presents complication of its own):

```
Modem <----> Router1 <---[DMZ]---> Router2 <---[LAN]
```

`Router1` is also a wireless access point and it makes a network which I'd call the "Public" network - it lets people connect but it doesn't give them access to my LAN. `Router2` is the inner router with an access point for my trusted devices. Both are consumer-grade routers and `Router1`'s "DMZ Host" setting is set to point at `Router2`. All the wires between `Router1` and `Router2` is the "DMZ" - the DeMilitarized Zone where untrusted devices live, and everything on the LAN side of `Router2` is the "LAN" - the stuff I trust.

The wireless network created by `Router1` though does *not* behave the same way as "Guest WiFi" because the typical implementation of Guest WiFi prevents guest clients from talking to each other and this does not.

Another much simpler option is to only have one of your routers make a Guest WiFi network.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The issue is that the primary router WiFi won't cover the entire house and I wanted seamless changeover to the secondary router for WiFi devices. I don't really need a guest mode as long as I can restrict the local network to trusted devices only and allow only internet access to others